# How do I get this symbol in Latex?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking to type this symbol in Latex:

[image]

I've been looking all over the place, but the only symbol that I find is the O for the Big-Oh notation, which looks as follows:

[image]

The Big-O symbol is more round, while the symbol I'm looking for is more oval

Comment: You can use [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to identify such symbols. This looks like `\mathcal{O}` from `\usepackage{ amssymb}`.

Comment: I am sorry but am I doing something wrong? I used the package `amssymb`  and `\mathcal{O}`, but I still get the big-O notation. I included the picture in the question.

The Big-O notation is more round, while the symbol I'm looking for is more oval.

Comment: I used the following code:

\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{O}$
\end{document}

Comment: Found it! It's in `\usepackage{euscript}` and you can call it with `\EuScript{O}`